# Methods in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, methods

I´m a newby on the java & android code. And I´m learning to write code for android in android Studio.

Now I have a simple question which will hopefully direct me in the right way.
I´m trying to make a supplylist where people can add or decrease the amount by pushing a button. For instance coca cola needs 6 more cans. You press the plus button 6 times.
Now I have about 30 of those items which each has it´s own plus and minus button.

Now my question. Do I need the write the button codes for each line (a line is "coca cola + 0 -"), or can I make a method which I can use for each line, so I don´t have to write each line over and over again? I want to make my code as clean as possible.

I have the following code:
    public void bestelling(int aantal) {
        TextView besteld = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CocaAantal);
        besteld.setText(String.valueOf(aantal));
    }

```
public void increase(View view){
    aantal = aantal + 1;
    bestelling(aantal);
}

public void decrease(View view){
    if(aantal < 1){
        aantal = 0;
    }else{
        aantal = aantal - 1;
        bestelling(aantal);}
}

public void reset(View view){
    aantal = 0;
    bestelling(aantal);
}
```

But this is just for one line.
I don't believe I have to do this for each line.

How do a realize a method that I can call upon to execute a increase and decrease everytime I push the button.

[A layout of what the app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Y2B.jpg)

Comment: Read about RecyclerView! It could be the solution for your question. [Check this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)

Comment: use custom view for that. here http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-custom-view-tutorial-part-1-combining-existing-views/ is the solution of your problem

Comment: you have to post what code you have, and ask a question about it so others can help you

Comment: @Yazan, I want to find out the code for myself. My only question is if it is possible.

Comment: my point is in order for people to understand what you ask, and try to provide answer, they need to know what you are talking about, what is the current code you have.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to write the same UI and UI handling code over and over again for each element. In fact, it's considered bad practice if you do.

In order to create a list of similar items, the Android framework offers list components such as [`ListView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) or the slightly more complex new [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html). There are explanation for both of them in the Android documentation, I suggest you have a look!